# How do I get the accuracy/precision of a h2o model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, h2o

I try to get the accurracy of my multiclass classifier using logistic regression.Is there any way to get the accuracy with a built-in function or do I have to write the function myself?

below my code so far:

```
multinomial_fit = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="multinomial",max_iterations=100)

multinomial_fit.train(x=train_h2o_cro.columns[1:],y=train_h2o_cro.columns[0],training_frame=train_h2o)

prediction_glm_h2o = multinomial_fit.predict(test_h2o)

multinomial_fit.model_performance(test_h2o)
```

With the last line of code, I only get the mse and nothing else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently unimplemented, but it makes sense to add this. Here is the [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3202) where you can track the progress.

Answer (score -2):

**Edited**

Because accuracy is not currently implemented as Erin pointed out, your options for evaluating the performance of your model are limited to the functions that are available to the H2OMultinomialModelMetrics.

for example you could look at the `.mean_per_class_error()`, take a look at the multiclass confusion matrix `model.confusion_matrix(data)`, or the log loss `.logloss()` to name a few.

Comment: Is `.logloss()` really returning the accuracy or precision of a model ? because when I look ip on the documentation, I get only the logloss it self. Do I have to do something more than printing printing the value?

Comment: @sedioben No, it's not returning accuracy.  Hopefully Lauren can fix the answer.

Comment: @sedioben I have updated my answer sorry for the confusion.